# BuildError(): error building a user of type

Tags: startup, error, macos

I'm getting a strange message each time I boot. For a quick second before the Apple Logo appears I see the text:

```
BuildError(): error building a user of type 0x20010008
```

Then the Logo appears, and shortly after the Login screen. After which the following errors appear:

```
BuildError(): error building a user of type 0x20010008
**** ERROR _CreateMenuWithWithIdentifier no image for file: 1_flag_menu_item.png
**** ERROR _CreateMenuWithWithIdentifier no image for file: 77_flag_other_menu_item.png
**** ERROR UIFlagPickerRestoreState No state found for flag picker
**** ERROR ArchiveViewCreateWithOptions ArchiveCopyPNGImage failed for file: preferences_good_samaritan_message_ribbon.png
**** ERROR ArchiveViewCreateWithOptions ArchiveCopyPNGImage failed for file: logimui_bootprogressbar.png
```

In verbose boot this is in big text before the usual status messages that show loading of the OS.

I'm was running OS X 10.10.4, and this began once I upgraded to the GM Candidate of El Capitan 10.11, which is the newest and stable release. Haven't a clue about what it is.

Any ideas as to what these messages are?

#### Update: Fresh Install

I just wiped my computer and did a fresh install of 10.11 GM El Capitan. Still showing up. Seems to be an issue of the new OS.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to correlate to enabling FileVault for the whole disk. I did that for my MBP since I use it for work and in the case it gets lost, I need the content to be protected.

When you boot from a disk completely encrypted by FileVault, the OS cannot boot until the password to decrypt the disk content is entered.

To do this, OS X starts a minimal LoginManager where you enter your user name and user password. The entered user password is used to decrypt the FileVault Key and FileVault can now decrypt the contents of the disk and the real boot sequence starts.

Usually this LoginManager offers a flag to select the language for its GUI and the Keyboard Layout. As it seems, Apple made an error by not providing the needed resources on the unencrypted partition for setting up the LoginManger. This results (in my humble opinion) in the following error messages at boot time (only to see for a very short time):

```
**** ERROR _CreateMenuWithWithIdentifier no image for file: 1_flag_menu_item.png
**** ERROR _CreateMenuWithWithIdentifier no image for file: 92_flag_other_menu_item.png
**** ERROR UIFlagPickerRestoreState No state found for flagpicker
**** ERROR AchiveViewCreateWithOptions ArchiveCopyPNGImage failed for file:  preferences_good_samaritan_message_ribbon.png
**** ERROR AchiveViewCreateWithOptions ArchiveCopyPNGImage failed for file:  loginui_bootprogressbar.png
```

When you logoff a user and get back again to the LoginManager AFTER the system has booted, you will see the flag, the language menu, and the power off menu, which you don't see directly after switching on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a consequence of protecting with Firevault your boot disk. if it is enabled the EFI is not allowed to read or write from the boot disk at that early stage in the EFI initialization Sequence.

My best guess at this moment is that this behavior is intended, a new security feature present in OS X 10.11 El Capitan.

Apple will need to publish an EFI update to get ride of the deprecated "warning messages".

Comment: I can verify this is not the case, as FileVault was enabled by default in Yosemite, and this error did not occur until El Capitan.